# Accurate way to measure request/response times of an Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

Consider the following code for measuring request/response times in an Asp.Net application:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
         (DateTime.Now - HttpContext.Current.Timestamp).TotalMilliseconds,
         HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl));
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx), `DateTime.Now` has an approximate resolution of 10 milliseconds.

Also, from [MSDN HttpContext.Timestamp description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.timestamp.aspx),

> The timestamp returned from the `Timestamp` property is the local time of the server and is set during the instantiation of the `HttpContext` object. The local time is equal to the UTC time plus the UTC offset.

The above code should in theory then give me the total request/response time in milliseconds.

My question is, how accurate is this going to be?  And is there a more accurate / better way of going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StopWatch class can potentially have accuracy down to microseconds depending on the hardware and operating system.  There is a IsHighResolution property to read if you're in high resolution mode.  If not then your are down to the accuracy of system timer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

The up side of using this class is you will certainly be no worse that the code above.  If on hi-res, you'll get much more accuracy.

But, if you're trying to measure performance and get better insight into your service, then there are better tools.

For example, perfview is a good tool:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I did consider this, however I would have to start (and store) the StopWatch somewhere. The HttpContext.Current.Timestamp is added quite early in the pipeline so seems like a good place to measure response times from.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer and will append your answer with the solution.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using the miniProfiler in your code, I've found it is pretty neat and useful:

http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: Thanks Druegor, this looked really good but I've gone with the approach above :-)

Comment: MiniProfiler is definitely the way to go but only if you can not use New Relic Agent on your IIS Server - https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/